# How to change interface language at runtime?

Tags: delphi, localization, delphi-2010

I'm using embedded Delphi 2010 localization tools and I can't find the way how to change interface language at runtime. So, how can I change interface language at runtime ?

Answer (score 3):

VCL is not designed such way that it would make runtime language switch easy. The RichEdit demo is actually using form reallocation. It is too strong action for a language switch because you will lose everything you have done for the forms on runtime.

Some localization tools have implemented add-on to VCL to implement runtime language switch. Some use components together with proprietary translations data to perform this. Some use the standard resource DLL with some units linked to application to perform language switch. For example take a look at this document. It describes step by step who to perform runtime language switch without needing to reallocate forms and without losing any data.

http://www.sisulizer.com/translation/vcl/VCL.pdf

Be careful with arrays containing resourcestring!

Answer (score 2):

See the RichEdit demo in Demos\DelphiWin32\VCLWin32\RichEdit directory.

Comment: I don't have such folder. Delphi 10.3. Where is it? There is no RichEdit demo in "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Samples\Object Pascal\VCL"

Comment: @MehmetFide This was an old demo since Delphi 7. It's not included with 10.3 anymore for some reason. Found something which looks similar [here](https://github.com/caiovinic/RichEditXE5).